# Marshal arbitrary XML attributes in an element in Go?

Tags: xml, go

I need to marshal in extra attributes on an element at runtime. I've tried this:

```
type Meh struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Attrs []xml.Attr
}

Meh{
    Attrs: []xml.Attr{
        xml.Attr{xml.Name{Local: "hi"}, "there"},
    },  
}
```

But the fields are treated as new elements:

```
<Meh><Attrs><Name></Name><Value>there</Value></Attrs></Meh>
```

If I add the tag `xml:",attr"` to the `Attr` field, it expects a `[]byte` or `string` specifying the contents of a single attribute.

How do I specify attributes at runtime? How do I annotate the type to provide field(s) for this?

Answer (score 2):

You might try working directly with templates.  Example:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "text/template"
)

type ele struct {
    Name  string
    Attrs []attr
}

type attr struct {
    Name, Value string
}

var x = `<{{.Name}}{{range $a := .Attrs}} {{$a.Name}}="{{xml $a.Value}}"{{end}}>
</{{.Name}}>`

func main() {
    // template function "xml" defined here does basic escaping,
    // important for handling special characters such as ".
    t := template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"xml": func(s string) string {
        var b bytes.Buffer
        xml.Escape(&b, []byte(s))
        return b.String()
    }})
    template.Must(t.Parse(x))
    e := ele{
        Name: "Meh",
        Attrs: []attr{
            {"hi", "there"},
            {"um", `I said "hello?"`},
        },
    }
    b := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := t.Execute(b, e)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Output:

```
<Meh hi="there" um="I said &#34;hello?&#34;">
</Meh>
```

Comment: What happens if an attribute value contains a double-quote character? Seems like you need to add intelligent escaping.

Comment: Very true.  Maybe I'm guilty of not adding a warning that the code is just a sketch.  I think escaping is best done with template functions and in most applications it would probably be appropriate to define one or more of these.  A start would be one that just called xml.Escape.  I imagine a more intelligent function would be called for in many cases.